# Two-step verification using JSch library

Tags: java, ssh, jsch

I am trying to use Java to connect to a Linux server which has a two-step verification login. I'm using the JSch library, this is the code I've got so far:

```
session = jsch.getSession(username, ip);
Properties config = new java.util.Properties(); 
config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
session.setConfig(config);
        
session.setPassword(password);
session.connect();
System.out.println("Connected to " + ip);
```

Obviously when I run this script I get an *"Auth failed"* error as I haven't enter the authentication key. So how do I login using the verification key. If this isn't possible could someone suggest a library that has this functionality.

This is logging into the server using putty. So you enter the username, then the time based generated code, then the password.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I worked this out eventually, you have to implement `UserInfo` and `UIKeyboardInteractive`. Use the `promptKeyboardInteractive` method, to make it return the authentication key, shown in the following code which works for me:

```
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;

import com.jcraft.jsch.Channel;
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelExec;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;
import com.jcraft.jsch.UIKeyboardInteractive;
import com.jcraft.jsch.UserInfo;

public class UserAuthKI{
  public static void main(String[] arg){

    try{
      JSch jsch=new JSch();

      String host="";
      String user="";

      Session session=jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);

      // username and passphrase will be given via UserInfo interface.
      UserInfo ui=new MyUserInfo();
      session.setUserInfo(ui);
      session.connect();

      Channel channel =session.openChannel("exec");
      ((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand("echo 'hello'");
      
      channel.setInputStream(System.in);
      channel.setOutputStream(System.out);

      channel.connect();
      
    }
    catch(Exception e){
      System.out.println(e);
    }
  }

  public static class MyUserInfo implements UserInfo, UIKeyboardInteractive{
    public String getPassword(){ return "passwordHere"; }
    public boolean promptYesNo(String str){
      return true;
    }

    public String getPassphrase(){return null;}
    public boolean promptPassphrase(String message){ return false; }
    public boolean promptPassword(String message){
      return true;
    }
    public void showMessage(String message){
      System.out.println(message);
    }

    public String[] promptKeyboardInteractive(String destination,
                                              String name,
                                              String instruction,
                                              String[] prompt,
                                              boolean[] echo){
    
      System.out.println("destination: "+destination);
      System.out.println("name: "+name);
      System.out.println("instruction: "+instruction);
      System.out.println("prompt.length: "+prompt.length); 
    
      String[] str = new String[1];
    
      if(prompt[0].contains("Password:")){
        str[0] = getPassword();
      }
      else if(prompt[0].contains("Verification code: ")){
        try {
          str[0] = PasswordUtils.verify_code("CODEHERE");
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
      else{
        str = null;
      }
    
      return str;
    }
  }
}
```

(`PasswordUtils.verif_code()` is the static method which generates the key)