# JSch - Is there a way to connect to a SFTP server if it requires MFA, i am getting SocketTimeoutException

Tags: java, security, sftp, jsch

I am able to connect to our SFTP server using WinScp(sftp client app) but before that i need to establish a session locally using MFA.
Now i am trying to achieve this programmatically using JSch but i am getting SocketTimeoutException 
because i think it requires the same MFA setup to be done programmatically, if my understanding is correct then is there a way to achieve this using JSch ?

```
JSch jsch = new JSch();
Session session = jsch.getSession(userName, hostName, 22);
session.setPassword(password);
session.connect();
```

It throws exception at session.connect().

Comment: What's that setup of WinSCP and MFA? Can you show it here? There are configuration options in JSch, like `session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");`, for example.

Comment: I have tried with StrictHostKeyChecking as well , it did not work. Regarding setup -we have a url where we need to enter our id and a token from a MFA app. And after that we can connect to servers in our client's (e.g. aba.com) network.

Comment: Well, I don't really know a solution. I would check all possible configurations, maybe your use case is somehow covered. Start with the [JavaDocs of JSch](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/JSch.html#setConfig-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-). There is also [another possibly related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39396209/two-step-verification-using-jsch-library).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am closing this question myself as there is no additional setup is required for this. From the machine on which this code is getting executed, if that machine has established the MFA session then it should work seamlessly and without making any other change.
It did not work for me earlier because my MFA session was expired.