# libpam-google-authenticator. Couldn't authorize with gradle pugin org.hidetake.ssh

Tags: gradle, ssh, jsch, google-authenticator

I'm trying to log in to the SSH host using the user, private key and google authenticator, via Gradle plugin: 'org.hidetake.ssh' but I get error:

com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth cancel for methods 'keyboard-interactive'

At the same time, I can connect to the server through a regular ssh client and it asks for an otp code that I enter and go to the server.

```
remotes.create('preprod') {
    host = '10.10.10.10'//todo old IP
    user = 'test'
    identity = file(adminKeyPath)
    knownHosts = allowAnyHosts
}
```

I expect that the script will request an otp code in VSCode for authorization on the server

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, the plugin `org.hidetake.ssh` is not capable of processing user input.

It should be possible, but currently not with this plugin.

Compare Jsch example at https://stackoverflow.com/a/39511487/2290153